# What is the proper way for including a file under root directory when using pyscript with pyodide-worker option?

Tags: python, visualization, panel, pyscript

I am trying out pyscript as one of the ways to share interactive dashboards with others. I have been able to get "hello world" to work. In my example, which is a quite common situation, I need to visualize a dataset, preferably embedded in the .html or a zipped folder that the receiver can just **open-and-see.**

I am also able to include the data file with the new syntax:

```
<py-config>
packages = ['some_package'] 
[[fetch]]
files = ['./data.csv']
</py-config>
```

But the above code requires the output to be 'pyscript' mentioned in the following tutorial:
[Running Panel in the Browser with WASM](https://panel.holoviz.org/user_guide/Running_in_Webassembly.html)

It is written in the tutorial that the 'pyscript' option is less performant than the 'pyodide-worker' option. For me, rendering the .html file that is exported by 'pyscript' options is too slow.

So I generated the .html file using the 'pyodide-worker' option. It generates a .html along with a .js file of the same name. Then, I manually added those lines to the .html file.

But when I hosted an http server and accessed the .html file, the error message was that the file data.csv cannot be found (triggered when using the file later in the code). It would seem the syntax is not working (and probably ignored). How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the following article:
[How can I load external files in Pyodide?](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/faq.html#how-can-i-load-external-files-in-pyodide)

Inside <filname.js>:

```
async function startApplication() {
...
console.log("Packages loaded!");
  
  let zipResponse = await fetch("data.zip");
  let zipBinary = await zipResponse.arrayBuffer();
  pyodide.unpackArchive(zipBinary, "zip");
  console.log("Files imported to vitual storage system!");
...
}
```